# How can I set a bash alias that evaluates $() when run?

Tags: bash, alias

I set up an alias:

```
alias gpgagentexport="eval $(cat ~/.gpg-agent-info) ; export GPG_AGENT_INFO"
```

However when I source my `.bashrc` the `$(cat ...)` is evaluated at that point.  But I want to evaluate it when I run the alias `gpgagentexport` (after the contents of `~/.gpg-agent-info` has changed).

So is there some sort of escaping, quoting or syntax to achieve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
alias gpgagentexport='eval $(cat ~/.gpg-agent-info) ; export GPG_AGENT_INFO'
```

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I should go and read a bit more about bash quoting rules.

Answer (score 8):

Escaping the `$` should also work:

```
 alias gpgagentexport="eval \$(cat ~/.gpg-agent-info) ; export GPG_AGENT_INFO"
```

Comment: This answer worked better for me, as I had single quotes in my command.